# Is it possible to have a nullable foreign key in this scenario?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create the 'teams' table with a foreign key to the competitions table, but how can I set the foreign key on nullable?

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('place');
    $table->string('competition')->nullable()->default(null);
    $table->foreign('competition')->references('name')->on('competitions')->onDelete('set null');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('competitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Foreign keys needs unqiue values,otherwise how do you know which is which.You need a many to many relation - a team can enter many competitions,a competition ca host many teams-so create an intermediary table competitions_teams with foreign keys to both tables.

Answer (score 2):

It's acceptable for a FK to be nullable, it just means your team doesn't belong to a competition yet so I think you have the right idea.  I am guessing you are getting an error because you are trying to relate your `teams` table to `competitions` table before the `competitions` table has been created.

Create the `competitions` table first.  You may need to drop your `teams` table first if it was created and try running the migration again.

It may also be an issue relating it on the `name` column.  Ideally, you should be naming that column `competition_id` instead of `competition` and relating it on the `id` column in your `competitions` table.  Having the `name` column on the competitions unique like you have should have the desired effect but queries may be slower because it's creating a larger index having it on a varchar.

If you do it on the `name` column you may have more issues down the road if you need to update the competition name.  If you are relating on the id, this should never be an issue because you generally don't change ids.  I think yours can still work this way, you would just need to add an `onUpdate('cascade')` as well to your FK.

Comment: is there a way to somehow prioritize migrations?

Comment: Since you have both of these in the migrations, just move the `competitions` table up.  If these were in different migrations, remove the key from the `teams` migration and in the new migration where you create `competitions`, create the table, then create the foreign key in that migration.  Otherwise, you can manually change the timestamp on the migration file names and run them again although this might cause some issues with your database.  You might need to truncate the migrations table and drop all your tables, then migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create `competitions` table first, before create `teams` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Schema::create('competitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name')->unique();
     $table->timestamps();
});    

Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name')->unique();
      $table->string('place');
      $table->string('competition')->nullable()->default(null);
      $table->timestamps();
 });

Schema::table('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreign('competition')->references('name')
      ->on('competitions')->onDelete('set null');
 });
```